# PHP form that shows secret page when user submits name & email

Tags: php

I'm basically trying to create a form that collects a users name, email and company, mails that information to me, and then opens up a secret page to them. I think I'm on the right track, hoping you guys can help me out.

**Form:**

```
<form id="form1" action="submit.php" method="post">
            <label for="name-id" >Full Name</label>
            <input id="name-id" name="name-id" type="text"/>
            <label for="email-id" >Email</label>
            <input id="email-id" name="email-id" type="text"/>
            <label for="company-id" >Company Name</label>
            <input id="company-id" name="company-id" type="text"/>
            <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
$name = $_POST["name-id"];
$email = $_POST["email-id"];
$company = $_POST["company-id"];

if($name != null && $company != null && filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL){
    echo "all forms filled";
    mail("me@me.com", "subject - success", "body - someone passed"); 
    include ("secretpage.php");
    exit();
} else {
    include ("homepage.php");
} ?>
```

Comment: What the problem, this looks fine.

Comment: it's better to redirect user to secure page to prevent duplicate form submission when refreshing, but you need to use SESSION also.

Comment: you should capture by this way $name=isset($_POST["name-id"]) ? $_POST["name-id"] : NULL; and check in the if(!empty($name)&& !empty($company) && filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))

Comment: What is the question? If you are asking for comments, then this is the wrong board for it.

Comment: This might be a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm confused, what's the question? :O

Comment: Just turned on PHP errors.. something's up with the If statement

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /Users/msavin/Desktop/Wavicle/index.php on line 21

Comment: The first thing you should do if you get a blank page or something isn't behaving correctly is to check your error log (or turn on the PHP flag to show errors if it's safe to).

Comment: Maybe you can use header() instead of include()? or maybe force http_redirect? See here http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.http-redirect.php

Answer (score 0):

Max,

You should redirect your customer to secretpage or homepage instead of include files in a same page.

You can do it by using javascript, window.location="secretpage.php" or window.location="homepage.php" depends upon an authentication.

If your code is not working remove "filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)" from your if condition. write error_reporting(E_ALL) and ini_set("display_errors",1) at the top of your page code, which will help to track an error.